# How to filter with an array inside array object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the data:

```
userRoom = ['rm1'];

    data = [{
      name: 'building 1',
      building: [{
       room: 'rm1',
       name: 'Room 1'
      },{
       room: 'rm2',
       name: 'Room 2'
      }]
     },{
      name: 'building 2',
      building: [{
       room: 'rm3',
       name: 'Room 3'
      }]
     },{
      name: 'building 3',
      building: [{
       room: 'rm1',
       name: 'Room 1'
      }]
     }]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to display the data which it has a building `room1` and filter it.

expected output will be like this:

```
 [{
      name: 'building 1',
      building: [{
       room: 'rm1',
       name: 'Room 1'
      },{
       room: 'rm2',
       name: 'Room 2'
      }]
     },{
      name: 'building 3',
      building: [{
       room: 'rm1',
       name: 'Room 1'
      }]
     }]
```

What I did is

`data.map(x => x['building'].filter(y=> userRoom.includes(y.room));`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to `filter` on `data`. In that filter, you need to check that `some` of the rooms in `x.building` have the correct `room`... So, if you replace `map` with `filter`, and `filter` with `some`, you should have it working.

Comment: Here we go! `var result = data.filter(f => f.building.some(s => userRoom.indexOf(s.room) > -1));`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) > [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) > [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for the cleanest solution:

```js
userRoom = ['rm1'];

data = [{
  name: 'building 1',
  building: [
    { room: 'rm1', name: 'Room 1' },
    { room: 'rm2', name: 'Room 2' }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'building 2',
  building: [
    { room: 'rm3', name: 'Room 3' }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'building 3',
  building: [
    { room: 'rm1', name: 'Room 1' }
  ]
}];

let filtered = data.filter(i => 
  i.building.some(j => 
    userRoom.includes(j.room)));

console.log(filtered);
```

To elaborate on why this works:

- You want to `filter` the `data` array, as you want so select which of the entries in there you do and don't want to have returned.
- To determine which building passes the test required for the `filter`, `some` of the rooms in that building need to match a rule...
- This rule is that the room's identifier has to be included in the `userRoom` array, hence the use of `includes`.

Answer (score 0):

This cant be done with `Array.map`, because, `Array.map` always returns a node against each node of the input array. Try making use of any other looping logic.

`Array.filter` with `Array.some` will do the trick

```js
const userRoom = ['rm1'];
const data = [{"name":"building 1","building":[{"room":"rm1","name":"Room 1"},{"room":"rm2","name":"Room 2"}]},{"name":"building 2","building":[{"room":"rm3","name":"Room 3"}]},{"name":"building 3","building":[{"room":"rm1","name":"Room 1"}]}];
const output = data.filter((curr) => curr['building'].some(y=> userRoom.includes(y.room)));
console.log(output);
```

What you have to do is filter the `data` array with some condition.

Your condition is true, so use that with `Array.some`. Filter the `data` with this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const data = [{"name":"building 1","building":[{"room":"rm1","name":"Room 1"},{"room":"rm2","name":"Room 2"}]},{"name":"building 2","building":[{"room":"rm3","name":"Room 3"}]},{"name":"building 3","building":[{"room":"rm1","name":"Room 1"}]}];

const anyUserRoomInBuilding = 
(building, userRoom) => building.some(({room}) => userRoom.includes(room));

const getBuildingsByUserRoom = 
(data, userRoom) => data.filter(({building}) => anyUserRoomInBuilding(building, userRoom))

console.log(getBuildingsByUserRoom(data, ['rm1']));

// console.log(getBuildingsByUserRoom(data, ['rm3', 'rm1']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let filtered = data.filter(i => {
  return i.building.filter(j => {
    return userRoom.includes(j.room);
  }).length > 0;
});
```

```js
userRoom = ['rm1'];

data = [{
  name: 'building 1',
  building: [{
    room: 'rm1',
    name: 'Room 1'
  }, {
    room: 'rm2',
    name: 'Room 2'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'building 2',
  building: [{
    room: 'rm3',
    name: 'Room 3'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'building 3',
  building: [{
    room: 'rm1',
    name: 'Room 1'
  }]
}]

let filtered = data.filter(i => {
  return i.building.filter(j => {
    return userRoom.includes(j.room);
  }).length > 0;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Why `.filter(<..>).length > 0`? Just use `.some`.